# How to enable basic authentication without user sessions with ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack, basic-authentication

According ServiceStack github [wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) In order to add/enable basic authentication in ServiceStack following lines of code are required:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
      new IAuthProvider[] { 
        new BasicAuthProvider(), //Sign-in with Basic Auth
        new CredentialsAuthProvider(), //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
      }));
```

But how can I add basic authentication without user sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform the authentication without using sessions then you can create a simple request filter that performs the basic authentication yourself.

You can then authenticate the credentials either against your own database or repositor, or you can authenticate against the standard ServiceStack repository *shown below*:

```cs
public class MyAuthenticateAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        // Determine if request has basic authentication
        var authorization = req.GetHeader(HttpHeaders.Authorization);

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // Decode the credentials
            var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authorization.Substring(6))).Split(':');
            if(credentials.Length == 2)
            {
                // Perform authentication checks. You could do so against your own database
                // or you may wish to use the ServiceStack authentication repository IUserAuthRepository

                // If you want to check against ServiceStacks authentication repository
                var repository = HostContext.TryResolve<IUserAuthRepository>();
                if(repository == null)
                    throw new Exception("Authentication Repository is not configured");

                // Try authenticate the credentials
                IUserAuth user;
                if(repository.TryAuthenticate(credentials[0], credentials[1], out user))
                {
                    // Authenticated successfully

                    // If you need the user details available in your service method
                    // you can set an item on the request and access it again in your service
                    // i.e. req.SetItem("user", user);
                    // In your service: Request.GetItem("user") as IUserAuth

                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        // User requires to authenticate
        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        res.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.WwwAuthenticate, "basic realm=\"My Secure Service\"");
        res.EndRequest();
    }
}
```

So instead of using the `[Authenticate]` attribute you would use the `[MyAuthenticate]` attribute.

In your `AppHost` `Configure` method do not add the `AuthFeature` plugin. You do still however need to add the repository, if that's how you choose to authenticate the credentials against.

```cs
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);
```

I hope this helps.